# Does APK Decoding shows JSON keys accumulated in JSON object?

Tags: android, json, web-services, apk, decoding

Does APK code decoding reveal jsonObject.accumulate(key,value) lines of code .
if yes how could static keys for JSON object kept hidden from being shown on decoding APK.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html 
Proguard is a tool which obfuscates and optimizes as well as shrinks APKs.

Comment: thanks that was helpful .
can you tell how to add it to adt. i read link content but i wasn't able to figure it out where to start adding Proguard in Android ADT .

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

All code and strings in your program can be easily recovered from the APK.

Things can be *obfuscated*, but not protected entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not meaningful and filled with lots of machine level conventions, but only your XML and Constant values can be regained exactly.